# Use of Indirect function in Excel names

Tags: excel, names

So I'm doing something a "little" crazy. I'm trying to tweak a long series (1000 terms) and I don't want to drag and drop over 1000 lines every time I modify my formula.

So in these 1000 lines is just a reference to a name, and this name contains the formula. But in it, I can't use the indirect function !

Why do I use it at all, you ask ? Well, my series calculates each term depending on previous ones, that's why.

So for example, each new term is twice the previous one, and the first one is 1. The formula is then :

```
=IF(ROW()<1;1;2*INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1;COLUMN())))
```

That works when directly in the 1000 cells, but when referred to via name, it says `#REF!`. And I isolated the fact that it was the `INDIRECT` function.

Any ideas how to solve or bypass that problem in a clean way ? Thanks in advance for your help !

Charles

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand fully your question, but my first suggestion is to forget `INDIRECT` and use a `Named Formula` instead:
- `Define Name`,
- name it "Previous"
- and enter the formula `=B2` (if you are in B3, and no $ in it to keep it relative).
Now you have a *named formula* called **Previous** that acts like a function returning the value the cell above.
Wouldn't that simplify your problem ?

At second thought, you might also use the `Offset` function here, instead of `Indirect` !

Comment: That's when it gets complicated : I actually want to refer to an arbitray number of terms backwards - and keep the value in a cell, and mess around with it (or with the formula in general).